# Как определить свойство font-size тэга body?

Tags: css3, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте. Как узнать свойство `font-size`, заданное в тэге `body` при помощи `css`-класса? При том, что то, какие `css`-классы будут заданы тэгу `body`, изначально не известны, как и неизвестно, в каком из классов будет определение и в каком виде, `font`, или `font-size`. Оизвестно точно одно: размер задается в процентах (напр. 112%). Ну и мне просто надо узнать этот процент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var FontSize = getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
```

Comment: Возвращает значение в пикселях. По-другому никак? Надо самому вычислять проценты?

Comment: На сколько мне известно, то получить можно только в пикселях.

Comment: Эх, печально. Придется составлять таблицу, переводящую пиксели в проценты. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Есть готовые функции в сети

Comment: Хм. Как я не подумал?